# JavaScript: Catch users who did screen

Tags: javascript

I need catch users who make screen on my web page. I can do it easy, if they use key "PrntScr", but what should i do if they make screen on Mac, Android or iPad? And can i catch users who make screen with other software?

p.s. sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 1):

It would be next to impossible for you to detect such behavior.  If your website was only available in the form of mobile apps you could detect when people take screenshots (as in the case of Snapchat), but it would be very easy for someone to bypass this on PCs.

In Linux, someone could use a tool such as `gnome-screenshot`; on Windows someone could use the `Snipping Tool`, and on any computer someone could use an extension to capture the screen.  If all else fails, someone could use a virtual machine to capture the screenshot without you knowing.